# NullInjectorError: No provider for FaConfig

Tags: angular, npm, font-awesome

Installed *angular-fontawesome* into angular app using npm like mentioned [in github](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#installation)

Works fine in development mode. But gave error in production build.

Of course the initial error was

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(Do)[qm -> t]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[qm -> t]: NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
```

Had to change setting in *angular.json* to

```
"optimization": false,
...
"buildOptimizer": true,
```

to find out the actual error

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FaIconComponent -> FaConfig]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FaIconComponent -> FaConfig]: NullInjectorError: No provider for FaConfig!
```

How shall I resolve this.

The module has

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
```

Added to imports

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
```

And component has

```
import { faEllipsisV, ... } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

like mentioned in how to guide.

Here are dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.11",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.0-alpha.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-webstorage-service": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
```

Angular Version `8.3.12.`

Comment: Just importing a class and doing nothin with it isn't sufficient. Read the guide again. You must add FontAwesomeModule in the imports of your NgModule decorator.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, not mentioned but the module was added in _imports_. The code works fine in dev, but fails in _--prod_

Comment: which Angular version are you using? can you post your dependencies?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an issue in the latest version 0.6.0-alpha.0, which may get installed automatically when you don't specify the version.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/210

You can downgrade to version 0.5.0 to resolve this AOT build error:

```
npm i @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.5.0
```

Comment: Didn't mention in the query but my version is 0.6.0-alpha.0. So might be it, will check and confirm.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.  My version was 0.6.0 and was unable to successfully load with ng build --prod, despite my app working with ng serve.  Downgraded to 0.5.0 and this worked great!

Answer (score 1):

**This error caused because of an updated version, as this issue still persists with 0.6.0-alpha.0, please downgrade your angular font-awesome library.**

*For example, use this command by specifying correct version :*

> npm i @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.5.0

Ps: Till angular8 It will work as I haven't tried this on angular8+

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to 0.5.0 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import fortawesome library, then to add the solid icons in it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas, faEllipsisV } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(fas, faEllipsisV);
```

Comment: import them, in module or component?

Comment: Definitelly in module

Comment: I tried as said. added library.add() to constructor. Also I did this for every module I used. One step ahead, I used fas, far combined. but no use.The error is still the same